# Are UDP sockets on Windows falling back to pipes on the same machine?

Tags: sockets, winapi, udp, pipe

Not sure whether this is true or not, whether it is platform specific, nor whether if there's a standard that forces an implementation to abide by such a rule, hence the question:

If one opens UDP sockets (WINAPI) to establish communication between processes on the same machine, will the communication actually be happening through pipes?

What is clear is that packets do not have to arrive in order, nor do they have to arrive at all.

Comment: Don't use quote formatting for text that isn't quoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If one opens UDP sockets (WINAPI) to establish communication between processes on the same machine, will the communication actually happening through pipes?

No. It will happen through UDP, via UDP sockets.

Comment: Any pointers on a more detailed explanation of what happens behind the scenes? I would like to better understand the differences between UDP on a local machine opposed to using UDP in a proper networking scenario.

Comment: The main difference is that the packets will be flowing through the loopback device (i.e. through a virtual network device) rather than an actual /physical Ethernet chip and network.